# How to add expiry headers in .htaccess file

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-translate

I add the following code in .htaccess file for expiry headers. It applied on all files but not applied on google translate css and js files.

```html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Can someone explain what is the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"